# C# Reflection: Unable to load System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, reflection, assembly.reflectiononly

In my project (running un .NET 4.5) I'm loading in `ReflectionOnly` context an assembly, which one of it's dependencies is `System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.

When I'm trying to load it with:

`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")`

I'm getting this exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I load this type properly?

Comment: You need to handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` event (that is the reflection-only counterpart of `AssemblyResolve` event) to handle assembly dependencies. In reflection-only they are **not automatically** resolved.

Comment: @Rubidium37, I know, when trying to load it from the event handler I'm getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the assembly and its dependencies are available in the application's probing path.

Here are a few possible solutions:

1. Add the assembly to the application's probing path: You can add the assembly to the application's probing path by using the Assembly.LoadFile method. For example:

```
Assembly.LoadFile("path_to_System.Net.Http.dll");
```

2. Use a binding redirect: If the assembly is already present in the probing path but with a different version, you can use a binding redirect to redirect the application to the desired version. You can do this by adding a  element to the application's configuration file (app.config):

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

3. Use a private assembly: If the assembly is not available in the probing path, you can load it as a private assembly. To do this, you need to use the Assembly.Load method with the LoadFrom parameter. For example:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("path_to_System.Net.Http.dll");
```

Once you have added the assembly and its dependencies to the application's probing path, you should be able to load it using Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad.